# Can't parse String to date format

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I cant figure out why this code won't work. Could anyone help me

```
String dateStr = "Thu Apr 02 09:49:16 CEST 2015";
DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");

DateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = null;
        try {
            date = readFormat.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String formattedDate = "";
        if (date != null) {
            formattedDate = writeFormat.format(date);
        }

        System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

My read format should be good unless im missing something.

I always get an java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Apr 02 09:49:16 CEST 2015"

On line: date = readFormat.parse(dateStr);

I tried the code on http://ideone.com/oBwtQo and it works there too. Why wont this work in NetBeans on my PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine, please check your imports, you would these classes

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is working perfectly

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String dateStr = "Thu Apr 02 09:49:16 CEST 2015";
    DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    DateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = readFormat.parse(dateStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String formattedDate = "";
    if (date != null) {
        formattedDate = writeFormat.format(date);
    }
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

Output: 2015-04-02 13:19:16

Please check your imports